# Using Razor 2 to write RSS fails on the <link> element

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2

I upgraded to MVC 4 yesterday and just discovered a bug that the upgrade introduced.

I have a Razor view that is used to generate an RSS feed. It has some markup like this (simplified):

```
<item>
    <title>@post.BlogPost.Title</title> 
    <link>@Url.BlogPost(post.BlogPost, isAbsolute: true)</link>
</item>
```

In Razor version two, there's [special support](http://vibrantcode.com/blog/2012/4/13/what-else-is-new-in-razor-v2.html/) for [HTML5 void elements](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/syntax.html#void-element). Such void elements are self closing, and do not have a closing tag.

Unfortunately, `<link>` is one such element.

This means the above Razor markup is no longer valid, and fails at runtime. Removing the closing `</link>` tag removes the parser error, but means that it's no longer valid RSS.

So, is there a way to get around this, or is Razor only really suitable for generating HTML5?

Comment: this is making me none too excited about razor 2...

Comment: @boomhauer, I think that making Razor 2 specific to HTML makes good sense for a markup language that is almost exclusively linked to HTML templating. I'm not sure that they couldn't have make it exclusive to a loose subset of XML (to allow for oddities such as `<br>` which are invalid in XHTML, but valid in HTML5), so perhaps it could be expanded to support valid XML that would not be valid HTML5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer to this question seems to be that Razor, as over version 2, is tied to HTML to the exclusion of XML.  I [asked one of the dev's for confirmation](http://vibrantcode.com/blog/2012/4/13/what-else-is-new-in-razor-v2.html/), so hopefully he gets back.

I ended up changing my method to use Linq to XML and a custom `ActionResult`, bypassing Razor and indeed any view engine:

```
[HttpGet]
[OutputCache(Duration = 300)]
public ActionResult Feed()
{
    var result = new XmlActionResult(
        new XDocument(
            new XElement("rss",
                new XAttribute("version", "2.0"),
                new XElement("channel",
                    new XElement("title", "My Blog")
                    // snip
                )
            )
        )
    );

    result.MimeType = "application/rss+xml";

    return result;
}
```

This requires the following custom `ActionResult`:

```
public sealed class XmlActionResult : ActionResult
{
    private readonly XDocument _document;

    public Formatting Formatting { get; set; }
    public string MimeType { get; set; }

    public XmlActionResult([NotNull] XDocument document)
    {
        if (document == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("document");

        _document = document;

        // Default values
        MimeType = "text/xml";
        Formatting = Formatting.None;
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        context.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
        context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = MimeType;

        using (var writer = new XmlTextWriter(context.HttpContext.Response.OutputStream, Encoding.UTF8) { Formatting = Formatting })
            _document.WriteTo(writer);
    }
}
```

Comment: Accepted my own answer as it doesn't seem possible to do this. If someone can demonstrate how to emit the XML element `<link>content</link>` using Razor 2 templates, I'll award them the answer.

Answer (score 12):

I'd do it like this:

```
<item>
   <title>
      @post.BlogPost.Title
   </title>

   @Html.Raw("<link>")
      @Url.BlogPost(post.BlogPost, isAbsolute: true)
   @Html.Raw("</link>")
</item>
```

Generated source will look like this:

```
<item>
    <title>
        Google
    </title>

     <link>
         http://www.google.se
    </link>
</item>
```

Comment: At this point you have to wonder why you're using a template engine! Doing the same with Linq-to-XML would be clearer, IMO. But it's good to know that you can use `Html.Raw` to work around the issue with void tags if needed.

Comment: I agree. What i like about this is that it at least resembles the produced output.

Comment: Drew: I cleaned it up a bit. Don't think it's too bad, especially if used as a partial. An RSS isn't that complex, but using Razor markup and partials for rendering big XSL-FO-files would probably be sweeter than using Linq-to-XML even if you had to use @Html.Raw on some elements.

Comment: It definitely looks nicer with your edit. Regarding your comment about it resembling the produced output: in the case of RSS at least, I actually prefer the Linq-to-XML picture of the output. It's closer to the conceptual model, for my mind at least. If laid out nicely, it looks more like [YAML](http://www.yaml.org/start.html) than XML.

Answer (score 2):

For now I go with this workaround:

```
 @Html.Raw(string.Format(@"<param name=""{0}"">{1}</param>",Name, Value))
```

Comment: Thank you very, very, very much! Was getting really frustrated with Razor! :D

Answer (score 2):

Since Alexander Taran has opened a bounty on this question in a search for a definitive answer to this, I thought I'd check out the [Razor source code on CodePlex](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/) and provide some detail.

Firstly, take a look at [`HtmlMarkupParser`](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/f079d76e57b5#src%2fSystem.Web.Razor%2fParser%2fHtmlMarkupParser.cs). It contains this reference data:

```
//From http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#elements-0
private ISet<string> _voidElements = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
{
    "area", "base", "br", "col", "command", "embed", "hr", "img", "input", "keygen",
    "link", "meta", "param", "source", "track", "wbr"
};
```

This is exposed via `HtmlMarkupParser.VoidElements`, and the only usage of this property is in [`HtmlMarkupParser.RestOfTag(...)`](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/f079d76e57b5#src%2fSystem.Web.Razor%2fParser%2fHtmlMarkupParser.Block.cs). This is a parser that's walking through a sequence of tokens. The relevant snippet of code is:

```
if (VoidElements.Contains(tagName))
{
    // Technically, void elements like "meta" are not allowed to have end tags. Just in case they do,
    // we need to look ahead at the next set of tokens. If we see "<", "/", tag name, accept it and the ">" following it
    // Place a bookmark
    int bookmark = CurrentLocation.AbsoluteIndex;

    // Skip whitespace
    IEnumerable<HtmlSymbol> ws = ReadWhile(IsSpacingToken(includeNewLines: true));

    // Open Angle
    if (At(HtmlSymbolType.OpenAngle) && NextIs(HtmlSymbolType.Solidus))
    {
        HtmlSymbol openAngle = CurrentSymbol;
        NextToken();
        Assert(HtmlSymbolType.Solidus);
        HtmlSymbol solidus = CurrentSymbol;
        NextToken();
        if (At(HtmlSymbolType.Text) && String.Equals(CurrentSymbol.Content, tagName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            // Accept up to here
            Accept(ws);
            Accept(openAngle);
            Accept(solidus);
            AcceptAndMoveNext();

            // Accept to '>', '<' or EOF
            AcceptUntil(HtmlSymbolType.CloseAngle, HtmlSymbolType.OpenAngle);
            // Accept the '>' if we saw it. And if we do see it, we're complete
            return Optional(HtmlSymbolType.CloseAngle);
        } // At(HtmlSymbolType.Text) && String.Equals(CurrentSymbol.Content, tagName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    } // At(HtmlSymbolType.OpenAngle) && NextIs(HtmlSymbolType.Solidus)

    // Go back to the bookmark and just finish this tag at the close angle
    Context.Source.Position = bookmark;
    NextToken();
}
```

This means that the following will be parsed successfully:

```
<link></link>
```

However the lookahead is limited, meaning that any extra tokens seen before the closing tag cause it to fail:

```
<link>Some other tokens</link>
```

It may be possible to extend the reach of the lookahead in this case. If anyone is keen, they can provide a pull request to the MVC team.

Comment: a good insight, but if anyone will make a pull request there should be an option to use razor to create custom xml, not just html

Answer (score 1):

Html5 link is a special element used in header for stylesheets and the like.

Your Rss should not be Html5 but something like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<rss version="2.0">
```

you could have this in a layout controller that your rss feeds would use

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<rss version="2.0">
    @RenderBody()
</rss>
```

An alternative way I've done it previosly is to have a completely empty view and then the controller below:

```
    [NHibernateActionFilter]
    public AtomActionResult Feed()
    {
        var dto = _service.GetThings(NHibernateSession);
        var items = Mapper.Map<List<ThingDto>, List<SyndicationItem>>(dto);
        var url = HttpContextWrapper.Request.UrlReferrer;
        var feed = new SyndicationFeed("MyTitle", "MyByline", url, items)
        {
            Copyright = new TextSyndicationContent("© 2012 SO"),
            Language = "en-IE"
        };
        return new AtomActionResult(feed);
    }
```

Of particular note is `System.ServiceModel.Syndication.SyndicationFeed`

And this is my custom result

```
 public class AtomActionResult : ActionResult
    {
        readonly SyndicationFeed _feed;

        public AtomActionResult() { }

        public AtomActionResult(SyndicationFeed feed)
        {
            _feed = feed;
        }

        public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
        {
            //context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/atom+xml";
            //chrome does not yet support atom+xml 
            //http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=104358
            context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/xml";
            var formatter = new Atom10FeedFormatter(_feed);
            using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(context.HttpContext.Response.Output))
            {
                formatter.WriteTo(writer);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Right, my RSS is not HTML5 -- it's just plain XML. However it seems that the new version of Razor is coupled to HTML5 and so cannot produce valid XML documents that have `link` elements with content. I'm interested in whether it's possible to tell the Razor parser to ignore the rules around void elements. I haven't found a way to do this yet.

Comment: Also, what's a layout controller? I'm guessing you mean some kind of helper function. If I was going to do that, then I'd just generate the entire response in the action method using Linq-to-XML and avoid Razor. I'm mostly interested in knowing whether this new version of Razor is limited to HTML only.

Comment: I'm using razor2 and don't have your issue. Could it be a compile or visual studio setting to be strict about this?  As per your post you would set content type to xml.  I'll update my answer with what I've done for an Atom feed.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but you're not using Razor to render out the view of the XML document. I'm mostly interested in knowing whether this new version of Razor is limited to HTML only.

Comment: @DrewNoakes not in my latter suggestion with Syndication feed but I am in the first suggestion, with or without layout controller.  I do not believe it is limited to Xml but would suggest you consider using the built in support for feed generation.

Comment: If it is no longer possible to produce the XML element `<link>content</link>` in a template, then I'm saying that only a subset of XML is supported by Razor 2. And in my case (an RSS feed) I couldn't find a way to do this with Razor. Holding out for a categorical answer one way or another though.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is this:

```
@("<link>" + Url.BlogPost(post.BlogPost, isAbsolute: true) + "</link>")
```

much simpler